# Timezone as +0000 for format-dateTime

Tags: datetime, xslt, format, saxon

I'm trying to format the current datetime in XSLT with an explicit UTC offset (and no other literals and no millis), like: 20140710163601+0200.

However, this `<x:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[Y0001][M01][D01][H01][m01][s01][z]')"/>` gives me this: `20140710164200GMT+02:00`. Note that I do not want the `GMT` part.

If there is no offset, I get `20140710144546`.

Is there any way to force an explicit offset and set it to the format I want? Obviously, I could do some string manipulation, but maybe there's a library function I'm overlooking. And then there's the no-timezone result I have to force the format for.

Note that it's no problem for me to build a function around this, but rather I'd use something built in or more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSLT 2.0 spec of format-dateTime() is a bit muddled about timezones, so it may depend on which processor you are using. In 3.0 it's specified that you get the format you want with [Z0000]. Recent versions of Saxon implement the function according to the 3.0 spec, but other processors may well do something different. You might be better off using timezone-from-dateTime() to extract the timezone, and then formatting it using format-number().

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Tested for local timezone and UTC timezone. Local gives me +0200 and the UTC gives me +0000, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using (capital) Z instead of (lower-case) z.